# In PHP and Mysql, how do you execute a Mysql statement and display the results before the loop is finished?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, show

I have the following code below.  The goal is to execute a select statement, display the results and then execute the statement again.  I can't get it to work properly. When the code is executed without the loop, it works fine, but when the code is inside the loop, it just doesn't work.  The goal is to keep it looping forever, but display the results of each select statement during the "current loop run".  What am I missing? I would like it to display the result for each "run through" of the loop and then go back and do it again while sending the result to the browser with each successful loop iteration.  I've tried ob_implicit_flush and flush commands.

Thanks In Advance.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dict WHERE ID in (FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 662337))) ";

for ($i=1; $i =>1; $i++) {

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['word'];


};
```

Comment: Why do you want it to loop forever? Try looping only 10 times and see what happens

Comment: Since it loops forever the server will never answer to the client

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is using php/ajax.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function showQueryResult()
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getQuery.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
<script>setInterval("showQueryResult()",100);
<div id="txtHint" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And your getQuery.php page should look like this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM dict WHERE ID in (FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 662337))) ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['word'];

?>
```

Comment: resturns one result i'm pretty sure. He wants it to continually run and get a new word each time

Comment: I edited my code now using setInterval you can achieve what you want

Comment: so there really isn't an easy way to do this within php as one script, huh?